# Kafka KSQL - can't create streams due to timeouts

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I'm running 3 KSQL servers on Google's K8S towards Kafka (via ssl) and Zookeeper hosted on Google Cloud VM's. I can easily create 5 streams and they work perfectly, but everything beyond that gives me all sort of timeouts.

KSQL kubernetes config (ksql vars part):

```
            - name: KSQL_CONFIG_DIR
              value: "/etc/ksqldb"
            - name: KSQL_LOG4J_OPTS
              value: "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/ksqldb/log4j.properties"
            - name: KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
              value: ***:9092,***:9092,***:9092
            - name: KSQL_KSQL_INTERNAL_TOPIC_REPLICAS
              value: "3"
            - name: KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL
              value: "http://***"
            - name: KSQL_HOST_NAME
              value: prod-ksqldb-server
            - name: KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID
              value: "prod-ksqldb-server"
            - name: KSQL_LISTENERS
              value: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
            - name: KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING
              value: "0"
            - name: KSQL_SECURITY_PROTOCOL
              value: SSL
            - name: KSQL_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM
              value: ""
            - name: KSQL_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION
              value: /truststore/kafka.truststore.jks
            - name: KSQL_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: kafkassl
                  key: truststore_password
            - name: KSQL_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION
              value: /keystore/kafkaconnect.keystore.jks
            - name: KSQL_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: kafkassl
                  key: keystore_password
```

I'm getting following errors (randomly some of the occurs when I try to create stream, drop stream or describe stream extended):

```
Timeout while initializing transaction to the KSQL command topic.
If you're running a single Kafka broker, ensure that the following configs are set to 1 on the broker:
- transaction.state.log.replication.factor
- transaction.state.log.min.isr
- offsets.topic.replication.factor
Caused by: Timeout expired after 60000 milliseconds while awaiting
    InitProducerId
```

```
Failed to guarantee existence of topic ABC
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting
    for a node assignment. Call: createTopics
Caused by: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics
```

```
Failed to Describe Kafka Topic(s): [source_topic]
Caused by: Timed out waiting to send the call. Call: describeTopics
```

```
ksql> describe ABC extended;
[2021-08-27 11:04:05,458] ERROR Failed to list Kafka consumer groups offsets
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting
    for a node assignment. Call: listConsumerGroupOffsets
Caused by: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call:
    listConsumerGroupOffsets (io.confluent.ksql.cli.console.Console:344)
```

This one I've spotted in KSQL logs:

```
2021-08-27 13:53:34.055 CEST
[2021-08-27 11:53:34,054] INFO Retrying request. Retry no: 0 Cause: 'org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: findCoordinator' (io.confluent.ksql.util.ExecutorUtil:95)
```

We've checked Kafka logs, Zookeeper logs (I was supsecting some problems there due to getTopics problem), restarted both. No idea what's wrong.

As I said, Kafka broker itself works fine, there's Kafka Connect working on it too and no problems occurred...

Github issue: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/7953

EDIT:

1. Checked networking, seems okay.

   ping 10.164.0.30
   64 bytes from 10.164.0.30: seq=811 ttl=63 time=0.354 ms
   64 bytes from 10.164.0.30: seq=812 ttl=63 time=0.277 ms
   ^C
   --- 10.164.0.30 ping statistics ---
   813 packets transmitted, 813 packets received, 0% packet loss
   round-trip min/avg/max = 0.157/0.275/1.549 ms
2. Java memory is 3gb, used memory according to GKE dashboard is 1.5G.

Also, situation from today:
I've tried create stream today. Got response: `Statement written to command topic`. When I ran `SHOW STREAMS` I got

```
[2021-08-30 09:49:04,117] ERROR Timed out while waiting for a previous command to execute. command sequence number: 10 (io.confluent.ksql.cli.console.Console:344)
Error: command not executed since the server timed out while waiting for prior commands to finish executing.
If you wish to execute new commands without waiting for prior commands to finish, run the command 'request-pipelining ON'.
Timed out while waiting for a previous command to execute. command sequence number: 10
```

And it appeared after each try. When I closed the ksql-cli session and ran `show streams`, the error wasn't there but the stream which I created isn't there (maybe creating in background?)

Comment: Try adding more heap to the container? Maybe create a github issue?

Comment: to the KSQL container? It doesn't have limits. As for GH issue, I've created it a while ago, forgot to link https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/7953

Comment: @OneCricketeer there's 3gb -Xmx for java, used memory on the pod is 1.5GB (according to GKE dashboard).

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           12Gi       3.9Gi       2.1Gi       2.0Mi       6.7Gi       8.6Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

Comment: Hey, have you been able to figure out what was the problem with command topic? Im experiencing the same and kinda stuck...

Comment: I've switched to headless option and that solved the issue @Nikki

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts may have different reasons, the first is latency issue between kafka and ksql which it can be due to network latency or CPU botteneck in kafka that cause an await of ack for ksql's producer thread for over than 60000 ms or an await of response of ksql's consumer heartbeat which cause a consumer rebalance. The second reason is authorization issue. If you are using zookeeper acls, you have to be sure that ksql user is allowed to have the CREATE and Describeconfigs authorizations on all cluster, ALL authorization on _confluent-ksql topics and group, write and read on topics to use for your developpement.

Comment: As I said, this KSQL cluster already have existing running streams, but maybe there's something with ACKs. There's 5 streams already in, and ACK-ing takes too long, but hey, it's 60s! It's ages...

Comment: You can activate jmx on ksql to get client metrics (request latency, io wait time, ...). https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/monitoring/

Comment: I suggest that you do an analysis of ksql client's metrics and broker's metrics

Comment: I did an edit to original post with some new hints.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround by using ksql.queries.file and running it in a Headless mode. It works for me as I don't really need interactive version, but it doesn't solve issues with command topic.